# Mailmerge in Word from xls file with rows with cells that have comma seperated values

Tags: ms-word

I'm an absolute novice at this, but I've got an Excel'02 file with Cells in rows that have comma seperated values which I need for word mailmerge to split and add to newly inserted rows.

Now I've done this in Excel:

```
Sub tst()
Dim X As Variant
X = Split(Range("A1").Value, ",")
Range("A1").Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)
End Sub
```

How do I get Word to do just the same. Please?

Also please include the type of sub I should be using and how to reference anything like tables, cells, ranges etc

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it in Excel to a  scratch worksheet and then merge the data from there?